# What could happen when you call function returning int with void (*)() pointer?

Tags: c, windows, assembly, calling-convention

I would like to know what could happen in a situation like this:

```
int foo()
{
    return 1;
}
void bar()
{
    void(*fPtr)();
    fPtr = (void(*)())foo;
    fPtr();
}
```

Address of function returning int is assigned to pointer of void(*)() type and the function pointed is called.

1. What does the standard say about it?
2. Regardless of answer to 1st question: Are we safe to call the function like this? In practise shouldnt the outcome be just that callee (foo) will put something in EAX / RAX and caller (bar) will just ignore the rax content and go on with the program? I'm interested in **Windows calling convention** x86 and x64.

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: what does the compiler say ?

Comment: You can cast it like this freely. But you can't call it. Calling a function with a pointer of wrong type is undefined behavior.

Comment: Since there is a cast when assigning pointer all he can say is: ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya 
I know that realm of undefined behaviour is just not something one should allow in a program. Calling a function that returns a big struct with void() pointer could cause lot of harm - on x86 there would probably be no hidden pointer parameter, callee would try to write to some memory that he shouldnt and stuff like this. However in a simple int() called with void() shouldnt it be fine in practise?

Comment: in practice it'll work until it doesn't

Comment: @MarcinK. The standard says it is not okay for you to do that. If you are concerned about a particular implementation, you can try it out or look at the generated assembly. You mention the calling convention, but which compiler is used is also relevant to this.

Comment: It is UB, that's kinda obvious.  As is often common with UB you'll get away with it, *int* doesn't do a lot of damage.  In practice such a return value is stored in a processor register.  Which simply doesn't get used, you can't hear that tree fall in the forest.  You of course cannot get a warranty, write sensible code and you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: According to the standard it should be undefined behavior. However since you have the same set of parameters in both cases (no params), it will work in practice. Though your `bar` does not return any value and this might cause a different issue.

Comment: no any UB here. `int foo()` will be called and it return value ignored. `int foo()` is compatible with the type `void(*)()` - the same argument count and the same calling convention (however when we have 0 arguments - all calling conventions is the same). different only in return type - `void` vs `int`. but if we wait to `void` (so no wait for return value) - any return value is ok.

Comment: The cast is telling the compiler "I *know* this will work. Just do it!". So it stops telling you that it knows better. If it *had* worked, you wouldn't have needed the cast.

Comment: **2** yes - this is absolute safe, independ whatever said in docs or how it *interpreted*. need base on ownd understanding of internal implementation, how all this worked

Comment: @RbMm You are wrong. The types are not compatible. Note that "compatible" is a technical term defined by the standard. In particular: "For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types.*" (C99, 6.7.5.3/15) `int` and `void` are not compatible.

Comment: A very simple workaround is to have another function `void foo_wrapper() { foo(); }` and store a pointer to *that*. Then you are good.

Comment: @melpomene - what i say is based on my very deep understand of how it work internal. this is compatible cast. if we not wait for return value - any return value is ok

Comment: @RbMm What is this "it" whose internals you so deeply understand? It's not the C standard and it's not GCC. So what are you talking about?

Comment: @melpomene - i am talking about how c/c++ code converted to assembler (x86/x64), how all this worked. and i understand that here all ok,

Comment: @RbMm I would really like to know what is the deep understanding behind your claim? Can you quote any documentation from say the MSVC or gcc compiler that says it is okay to do so?

Comment: @RbMm "C/C++" is not a thing. Source code doesn't just magically turn into asm code. There is a compiler there doing the work, and it's a particular compiler in each instance (in a particular version, running with particular options). This can cause very different outcomes, especially when UB is involved. Frankly, you're being a bit obnoxious. I've cited the standard and I can point you to examples of compilers (e.g. gcc, clang) optimizing/removing code based on UB. All you're doing is citing your imagination ("deep understanding") and repeating yourself.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - all what i say based on on any documentation. i based on my personal knowledge. and i say that all absolute ok and safe in this case

Comment: @melpomene - if can - show example when this cast can give wrong result (by sense). very interesting will be look for it

Comment: @RbMm In that case, I would respectfully want to add that your personal knowledge is not adequate and I still maintain my position that it is not okay to make this call.

Comment: @RbMm No, you're the one making the claim it is safe. It is on you to provide evidence.

Comment: @melpomene - your problem (how and 99%) that you can not think yourself, but only "documentation" is god

Comment: @RbMm I would also accept source code. But I don't trust your "deep understanding" based on nothing.

Comment: @melpomene - what is source code you want to view ? i say that **2** - here all absolute safe and correct do this call. if you say that can be error in some case - can you give **concrete** example when this is can fail (give wrong/unexcepted) result ? what here wrong do this call ? not based on "documentation" but based on **understanding** how functions call at all worked

Comment: @RbMm Did you read my answer?

Comment: @melpomene - yes, read and not agree.

Comment: @RbMm -- if you disagree with the answers here, why don't you write a detailed answer which addresses what you see as shortcomings.

Answer (score 8):

1) 
From the C11 standard - [6.5.2.2 - 9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.2.2p9)

> If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is undefined

It is clearly stated that if a function is called using a pointer of type that does not match the type it is defined with, it leads to Undefined Behavior. 
But the cast is okay.

2)
Regarding your second question - In case of a well defined Calling convention XXX and implementation YYYY -

You might have disassembled a sample program (even this one) and figured out that it "works". But there are slight complications. You see, the compilers these days are very smart. There are some compilers which are capable of performing precise inter procedural analysis. Some compiler might figure out that you have behavior that is not defined and it might make some assumption that might break the behavior.

A simple example -

Since the compiler sees that this function is being called with type `void(*)()`, it will assume that it is not supposed to return anything, and it might remove the instructions required to return the correct value.

In this case other functions calling this functions (in a right way) will get a bad value and thus it would have visible bad effects.

**PS:** As pointed out by @PeterCordes any modern, sane and useful compiler won't have such an optimization and probably it is always safe to use such calls. But the intent of the answer and the example (probably too simplistic) is to remind that one must tread very carefully when dealing with UBs.

Comment: but in this *concrete* case behavior is known and defined. `int foo()` will be called and it return value ignored. `int foo()` is *compatible* with the type `void(*)();` - the *same* argument count and the same calling convention (however when we have 0 arguments - all calling conventions is the same). different only in return type - `void` vs `int`. however if we wait to `void` (so no wait for return value) - *any* return value is ok

Comment: @RbMm Actually no. Suppose we have a calling convention where the return value is pushed on the stack and in case of `void` nothing is pushed, the callee will end up not popping the value pushed, completely destroying the stack frame offsets. Again, the user mentions Windows X86 calling convention, but that is only for the second part of the question. I was answering the *What does the standard say about it?* part of the question.

Comment: *calling convention where the return value is pushed on the stack* - not exist this calling convention under windows now

Comment: Also, if the calling conventions are defined, a compiler with inter procedural analysis would figure out that this is a UB and might try to do an optimization which would break the behavior. Remember, compilers are only bound by the standard and not by the notion of what Users this is okay.

Comment: i say based on my deep internal understanding how all this work, how this implemented in asm code. and i understand that this is absolute safe do this kind of cast/call. (2 question)

Comment: @RbMm please read the example I have added in my answer to clarify the second part of the question. If you still disagree with my answer, you can post another answer clarifying why this is okay (Not meant in a rude or dismissive way).

Comment: *and it might remove the instructions required to return the correct value.* - what remove ? i not understand your "example" - can you be more concrete ?

Comment: @RbMm if the compiler sees that the `foo` is being called once with `void (*)()` it must be `void` returning and it might compile it to `foo: retq` causing a problem to other call sites.

Comment: and so what that `foo` is nothing returned ? effect of function call no only in return value. so in general call of function can not be suppressed because in return *void*. `bar`  also nothing returned. so you not prove any example. all what you say only empty by sense set of words.

Comment: @RbMm I am sorry, but respectfully I cannot take this discussion any further. You are free to post your own answer with whatever evidence you have stating it is "okay" to do this. I am sure the community will address it with relevant comments.

Comment: i very good know what 99% + thing about this, but most are not always right

Comment: and if you change to this https://godbolt.org/g/kRkwEz all ok. so your "example" nothing prove. you not build wrong effect. also if you change type of `foo` in your "example" to `void foo()` void - will be the same effect. you not build wrong by "sense" example

Comment: or how for you this - https://godbolt.org/g/id7dij "example" ? compiler drop call `void foo()` - but it already the **same** type. are this is "example" which something prove ?

Comment: @Ajay: I don't think it's likely that any good quality implementations (i.e. real compilers that people use) would make this optimization for a function that isn't "private".  i.e. it's not `static`.  However, clang `-fsanitize=undefined` does detect and warn about this UB (https://godbolt.org/g/NF7Lsk). I still think it's unlikely that gcc/clang would optimize based on it.  (They don't currently) .  clang/LLVM will optimize out the return-value part of a private function if the caller doesn't use it, but calling through a casted function pointer doesn't break it for other callers.

Comment: Oops, forgot to say that clang's sanitize check is only done in C++ mode, not for C (on Godbolt, use `-xc -std=c11`).  I guess it uses the C++ typeinfo infrastructure.

Comment: @Ajay: re: your statement that "*Remember, compilers are only bound by the standard and not by the notion of what Users this is okay.*"  The compilers that people actually use also aim to be useful.  It's possible to make a compiler that is fully standards-compliant but nearly unusable.  In general it's good to try to make your code 100% safe according to the standard, but quality-of-implementation goes far beyond "standards compliant".  I don't think I'd recommend invoking this UB if you can avoid it easily, though.  Maybe better to lie to the compiler in the prototype if you know the ABI.

Comment: @PeterCordes - actually seems reasonable that compilers would make this optimization for non-private functions. Do you mean that non-private prevents this optimization because it has to compile a fully correct version for external callers anyways, and the internal (same compilation unit) callers will use that too? Well gcc already clones functions (see `-fipa-cp-clone` for example) in cases where it sees that use by internal callers allows a simpler compilation (e.g., passing constants as parameters) and then it compiles the full version as well for external calls.

Comment: More relevantly, compilers already do fully inline calls through function pointers when it knows for sure the target function. So private or not, the function could easily get inlined.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: All I meant is that a good/useful compiler (like most aspire to be) won't break the global externally visible definition like this answer is suggesting.  A compiler *could* do that on this UB, but nobody wants that.  I ran out of room in my comment to word it better or mention cloning a private copy if it can't / doesn't want to inline.

Comment: @PeterCordes I understand your point about useful compilers and I fully agree with it, but I think I would have been wrong if I had written an answer saying it is okay to do so. OP has to be made fully aware of the consequences UB can have (optimizations related behavior changes are also hard to track). Yes, this particular example might work okay with a useful compiler. But we don't want OP to extend it and apply it to an example something might go wrong. I hope you understand my concern and the rationale behind this answer.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with your last comment.  I wouldn't recommend doing it in practice, because it's impossible to write a unit test for things that only break depending on context and it's not 100% certain that it will continue to work in the future, even if you limit to just gcc and clang.  My only objection to your answer is that your proposed mechanism for getting broken code is slightly too simplistic, and I just wanted to point out that real compilers aren't quite *that* dumb.  But it's the right *kind* of reasoning, so on second thought I am going to upvote because that's close enough.

Comment: @PeterCordes I will add a note saying that most compilers won't do this but it is something to be considered while extending the logic when having behavior that is not defined.

Comment: I added an answer showing some cases (with different return types) where this isn't safe even if the compiler behaves as we expect.  And also a way to use a weak to get an alternate prototype for the same block of machine code.

Comment: @PeterCordes - oh right, yes a compiler would almost certainly not break the externally visible function at all. Not only "because QoI" but because it would not be allowed: _possible UB_ at noticed compile time doesn't let it break a function which may be called outside of that path. Sure `bar()` has UB in the way it calls `foo()` but at runtime `foo()` may be called without calling `bar()` so the compiler has no license to mis-compile `foo()`. Imagine if that were true: if the compiler could detect any _potential_ UB anywhere it could mis-compile the whole program.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Oh right, I keep forgetting that UB in a function that never runs isn't actually UB.  If you use `-fwhole-program` or LTO, I think you could still be in trouble if the compiler proves that a UB-causing function does run.  But as you say, when producing separate `.o` files, they could be linked into different libraries or programs.  And in those programs, there may be a call to `foo()` from code that doesn't have UB.  Compilers that want to make demons fly out of your nose will have a tough job proving that they're allowed to do that here!

Comment: @PeterCordes - yes, with LTO the compiler could prove that `bar()` is always called from `main()`, but then it has a license to miscompile anything in your whole program, nothing to do with mis-compiling `foo()` specifically. In general it can miscompile any path that includes a guaranteed call to `bar()`. It occurs to me that a future use of UB would be to assume that branches that include UB don't occur, and compile the code accordingly as if they will never occur.

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen in a general way currently: even when clang detects guaranteed UB, it likes to put in an `ud2`, but then still compile checks that might branch to that `ud2`. Easier diagnosis, but slower...

Comment: @BeeOnRope: you mean `ud2` (x86's UnDefined instruction).  But yes, I like the idea of running `ud2` when there's no sane way for execution to continue.

Comment: Yes, I guess Intel didn't name the instruction after C/C++ UB :). Yes, I like `ud2` when you are in a path that's impossible/UB (or at least the kind of UB the compiler is deciding to ban based on the current settings). The tradeoff is gets more complex though when the compiler has to insert _extra_ code just to direct you to that UB. Imagine a long series of checks that could be completely removed if the `ud2` path(s) were assumed not to occur. It would be great to be able to remove them. @PeterCordes

Comment: As usual this isn't as interesting for "plain" code: why the hell would you have a path that is always UB? It's more interesting for code that is generated automatically, or generic code e.g., via templates. Even for plain code it matters when functions get inlined: for some parameter values maybe the compiler can detect that some paths through the function are UB: it's really important to eliminate the checks that lead to those paths: both saving the runtime cost of the checks and the i-cache hit of the UB paths (putting `ud2` already reduces the i-cache hit, but doesn't eliminate it).

Answer (score 5):

What happens in practice depends a lot on how the compiler implements this. You're assuming C is just a thin ("obvious") layer over asm, but it isn't.

In this case, a compiler can see that you're calling a function through a pointer with the wrong type (which has undefined behavior<sup>1</sup>), so it could theoretically compile `bar()` to:

```
bar:
    ret
```

A compiler can assume undefined behavior never happens during the execution of a program. Calling `bar()` always results in undefined behavior. Therefore the compiler can assume `bar` is never called and optimize the rest of the program based on that.

---

<sup>1</sup> C99, 6.3.2.3/8:

> If a converted
>   pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type,
>   the behavior is undefined.

Comment: *so it could theoretically compile bar() to:* - absolute not agree. this is **why** ?

Comment: @RbMm Because the C code has undefined behavior, so the compiler can do whatever it wants. It could even leave out the `ret`.

Comment: @RbMm You might want to read http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html and all linked articles.

Comment: what is UB ? call function by pointer ? again - can you yourself build and show concrete example (x86/x64) - with any comile and any optimization - which give here wrong result ?

Comment: @RbMm Dude, did you read my answer? There's a quote from the standard there that says what exactly is undefined.

Comment: @RbMm there might not be a compiler/optimization __today__ that breaks the behavior but new optimizations are written every day and one of them might break behavior. Contrary to your assumption, documentations/standards are actually "god".

Comment: again - here exist **concrete** example for this concrete case ? what can be wrong in this concrete cast ? you can not build poc example ?

Comment: @RbMm I can, but you didn't like it ("*absolute not agree*"). What do you want, then?

Comment: Our dispute is not about programming but about something more abstract. you are not free to do not documented things. I am free and have the right. *I can* - if can - show this example.

Comment: @RbMm You are free to do what you want, and you can test the results - on one particular version of one particular compiler running with one set of optimization options. The next version of the compiler (or a different compiler) may work differently. There's no guarantee that seemingly working code with UB will keep working in the future.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya That doesn't actually demonstrate a difference. Calling `foo` is a no-op.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - and what ? `foo` is empty. no no wrong effect here. try add for example some *external* call to `foo` and view effect

Comment: @melpomene - exist some general thing, which can not be changed or this will be compiler errors. compilers and now can drop any code which it thing have no sense. need look in any concrete case and understand. all what i wrote based on my understanding how functions is called. how c/c++ code converted to asm

Comment: @RbMm I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: @melpomene - i said that do this cast/call is safe and will be safe in future. with any optimization

Comment: @RbMm Yes, you're just repeating yourself. Have you read http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html yet?

Comment: @melpomene - what **concrete** it this page related to this example ?

Comment: your page is general examples of thin errors, ub, etc. but we dispute aboute concrete case

Comment: This is a very good point.  If the compiler can see the UB at compile time, breakage is possible even on targets where there's no asm-level calling convention problem (like on x86 with any of the Windows calling conventions).  A good-quality implementation would probably consider it a bug if it broke, but the question doesn't exclude the possibility of a hostile but standards-compliant compiler.  I'd agree with RbMn that this is probably safe in practice, but *not* because any standards guarantee it.  It's just a compiler QOI issue.  Function-pointer casting for API reasons does happen.

Answer (score 4):

About sub-question 2:

Nearly all x86 calling conventions I know (`cdecl`, `stdcall`, `syscall`, `fastcall`, `pascal`, 64-bit Windows and 64-bit Linux) will allow `void` functions to modify the `ax`/`eax`/`rax` register and the difference between an `int` function and a `void` function is only that the returned value is passed in the `eax` register.

The same is true for the "default" calling convention on most other CPUs I have already worked with (MIPS, Sparc, ARM, V850/RH850, PowerPC, TriCore). The register name is not `eax` but different, of course.

So when using these calling convention you can safely call the `int` function using a `void` pointer.

There are however calling conventions where this is not the case: I've read about a calling convention that implicitly use an additional argument for non-`void` functions...

Comment: *will allow void functions to modify the ax/eax/rax register* even more - this is volatile register. it must not be preserved during function call. if we not wait for some return value we simply ignore al/eax/rax value and of course not assume any value in it

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, exactly, **in all the normal calling conventions**.  But it's easy to imagine a calling convention where `eax` is call-preserved for `void` functions.  Irvine32 library functions use a non-standard calling convention that preserves all registers except `eax`, with the function arg passed in `eax`.  I'm not sure what it does for `void` functions, if there are any.

Comment: @Martin: melpomene makes a good point that if the compiler can see the UB at compile time, it's allowed to break.  (And might conceivably actually do so.)  It's theoretically only safe to apply reasoning like this based on the calling convention if the compiler can't see the definition of the function.  e.g. you wrote it in asm, or it's in another translation unit without LTO.  (And presumably also if the prototype you give it matches the way it's used.)  Any good-quality implementation would probably consider it a bug if this broke, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes - this is our source code. we **yourself** select calling convection (implicitly or explicitly). main understand - what we doing

Comment: @PeterCordes - honesty say i not view how this can cause wrong (by sense) result even if compiler view real signature of function. of course this cast and call exist sense do only if **at compile time** impossible say to where will point `fPtr` otherwise optimization replace indirect call to direct call `foo` . and compiler can drop `foo` call not because this "UB" but if it decide that `foo` do "nothing" - no any side effect from it call

Comment: @PeterCordes - and about documentation - exist also compiler bugs. for example something documented as defined - [*If size is 0, _alloca allocates a zero-length item and returns a valid pointer to that item.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca) - but ms *cl* compiler with optimization simply drop this call which cause real UB and critical bug in code which try use `alloca(0)`. and this bug exist how minimum 12+ years. so can be very different situation: not all undocumented fail. not all documented worked well

Answer (score 1):

**At the asm level only**, this is safe in all normal x86 calling conventions for integer types: `eax`/`rax` is call-clobbered, and the caller doesn't have to do anything differently to call a `void` function vs. an `int` function and ignoring the return value.

**For non-integer return types**, this is a problem even in asm.  Struct returns are done via a hidden pointer arg that displaces the other args, and the caller is going to store through it so it better not hold garbage.  (Assuming the case is more complex than the one shown here, so the function doesn't just inline when optimization is enabled.)  See the Godbolt link below for an example of calling through a casted function pointer that results in a store through a garbage "pointer" in `rdi`.

For legacy 32-bit code, FP return values are in `st(0)` on the x87 stack, and it's the caller's responsibility to not leave the x87 stack unbalanced.  `float` / `double` / `__m128` return values are safe to ignore in 64-bit ABIs, or in 32-bit code using a calling convention that returns FP values in `xmm0` (SSE/SSE2).

---

**In C, this is UB** (see other answers for quotes from the standard).  When possible / convenient, prefer a workaround (see below).

It's possible that future aggressive optimizations based on a no-UB assumption could break code like this.  For example, a compiler might assume any path that leads to UB is never taken, so an `if()` condition that leads to this code running must always be false.

Note that merely compiling `bar()` can't break `foo()` or other functions that don't call `bar()`.  [There's only UB if `bar()` ever runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072443/what-could-happen-when-you-call-function-returning-int-with-void-pointer/47089563?noredirect=1#comment81161267_47072626), so emitting a broken externally-visible definition for `foo()` ([like @Ajay suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072443/what-could-happen-when-you-call-function-returning-int-with-void-pointer/47072626#47072626)) is not a possible consequence.  (Except maybe if you use whole-program optimization and the compiler proves that `bar()` is always called at least once.)  The compiler can break functions that call `bar()`, though, at least the parts of them that lead to the UB.

However, it is allowed (by accident or on purpose) by many current compilers for x86.  Some users expect this to work, and this kind of thing is present in some real codebases, so compiler devs may support this usage even if they implement aggressive optimizations that would otherwise assume this function (and thus all paths that lead to it in any callers) never run.  Or maybe not!

An implementation is free to define the behaviour in cases where the ISO C standard leaves the behaviour undefined.  However, I don't think gcc/clang or any other compiler explicitly guarantees that this is safe.  Compiler devs might or might not consider it a compiler bug if this code stopped working.

**I definitely can't recommend doing this**, because it may well not continue to be safe.  Hopefully if compiler devs decide to break it with aggressive no-UB-assuming optimizations, there will be options to control which kinds of UB are assumed not to happen.  And/or there will be warnings.  [As discussed in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072443/what-could-happen-when-you-call-function-returning-int-with-void-pointer/47089563?noredirect=1#comment81161976_47089563), whether to take a risk of possible future breakage for short-term performance / convenience benefits depends on external factors (like will lives be at risk, and how carefully you plan to maintain in the future, e.g. checking compiler warnings with future compiler versions.)

Anyway, if it works, it's because of the generosity of your compiler, *not* because of any kind of standards guarantee.  This compiler generosity may be intentional and semi-maintained, though.

[See also discussion on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072443/what-could-happen-when-you-call-function-returning-int-with-void-pointer#comment81103468_47072626): the compilers people actually use aim to be *useful*, not just standards compliant.  The C standard allows enough freedom to make a compliant but not very useful implementation.  (Many would argue that compilers that assume no signed overflow even on machines where it has well-defined semantics have already gone past this point, though.  See also [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) (an LLVM blog post).)

---

If the compiler can't prove that it would be UB (e.g. **if it can't statically determine which function a function-pointer is pointing to**), there's pretty much no way it can break (if the functions are ABI-compatible).  Clang's runtime UB-sanitizer would still find it, but a compiler doesn't have much choice in code-gen for calling through an unknown function pointer.  It just has to call the way the ABI / calling convention says it should.  It can't tell the difference between casting a function pointer to the "wrong" type and casting it back to the correct type (unless you dereference the same function pointer with two different types, which means one or the other must be UB.  But the compiler would have a hard time proving it, because the first call might not return.  `noreturn` functions don't *have* to be marked `noreturn`.)

But remember that link-time optimization / inlining / constant-propagation could let the compiler see which function is pointed to even in a function that gets a function pointer as an arg or from a global variable.

---

### Workarounds (for a function before you take its address):

If the function won't be part of Link-Time-Optimization, you could lie to the compiler and give it a prototype that matches how you want to call it (as long as you're sure you got the asm-level calling convention is compatible).

You could write a wrapper function.  It's potentially less efficient (an extra `jmp` if it just tail-calls the original), but if it inlines then you're cloning the function to make a version that doesn't do any of the work of creating a return value.  This might still be a loss if that was cheap compared to the extra I-cache / uop cache pressure of a 2nd definition, if the version that does return a value is used too.

You could also define an alternate name for a function, using linker stuff so both symbols have the same address.  That way you can have two prototypes for the same block of compiler-generated machine code.

Using the GNU toolchain, [you can use an attribute on a prototype to make it a weak alias (at the asm / linker level).](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)  This doesn't work for all targets; it works for ELF object files, but IDK about Windows.

```
 // in GNU C:
int foo(void) { return 4; }

// include this line in a header if you want; weakref is per translation unit
// a definition (or prototype) for  foo  doesn't have to be visible.
static void foo_void(void) __attribute((weakref("foo")));  // in C++, use the mangled name

int bar_safe(void) {
    void (*goo)(void) = (void(*)())foo_void;
    goo();
    return 1;
}
```

[example on Godbolt for gcc7.2 and clang5.0](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSBnVAV2OUxAHIB6bgagB2qApj4EEAQwJ9kAGwkDgYTgz4AjWaimZ0MjKLyqAZsVQBbAKQAGAIK8%2BAWiMMFhPAC9MFgMwARZgJYRngCOnzoqCHAfMQBBHhmosgImMgA1gzWdvwQRgHI8agCYgCeAA5JKelRfEWyJXwhfADCFgBMAELtHXxm%2BgCUWVn2FgBsVgBukegQg%2BONqvgM8QIFfCbmfGNWIQSz28P8ACqS0hGYDALK0okKjQTKqsCRimKofJhmhHwS6qZpmGKywU6AcEk0oXCmGCAjcRUO6gaqDK8S%2B7hqLGk4lExEwBFYAgcE3BzFEy2YRiMjWK2I%2BAA8RMQBOD6kTDHgNKIgqQEWpmNJvmhmLJdE1sSQSqRehISmoDEDzEkSKFiDIJAxMAA6Ia2KZ4XSYBn7bxdWw67IAfQtUgIxA5/MwVqgQhCshCmH6g1su3WqFQED16H6WwA7KabHxI/S9oMTVkozE8QS%2BAAWHzhiwh3xZYHxZB8QO%2B1AWwMB6bBq02u18kRQADumAkaVxRgg7TaRj97c9sZ6fHsTVanW6UuYGrEKWlilkYWZiXNPrUEmIZf1wcz4YThYgACpnqh%2Bqug1s/Hwj7vD57O6h0/Go/vjZuo7j8Uy%2BFZb2as%2Bb7MBkPnXXdVRxFMZhgAQCdRAbJsWzAMAETkBRonOS5rilcQWHAqUmB%2BQtxEMakfj0LAl3HOsUlxBCimBAQCAcMpTDKCRgCkPAij4GcCGAyc0DMMo8BnYgEXbLAJjwYh8XBDwvDaNpalVcjtAmTBVRKFg1VkWREz6MTXlpEJ8FxAo2IEBFO1VZAWVUciVNEWk8lWQpijKF5GQWIjeP4mcHFRJUBBoghtW9Wj1GXC0XCMTAj3XMM70jbc9z9Q9A3XU9zx3S9%2BmvEtpk/CN7z9R84sTV9iloPLM2zM1qrsHc6vqhq%2BAAVX8iRIr4FzdhUhxLOWPgGoGnduHNZZYjWNQ8GAUbmDWDdiohaIFp%2BUg1FIZBSHQCrvzjWx7EszSanw7jQPAojSwy2ZwlQC4fgKZgWQaNRcSbEAEJZFSrouK5OGkJiGFUX4EH1LBnNclTNS2WxKwIW17REJ0IBdAQ3VCT0c1tGbpAmqaMbWbLpoKaLQyfSNDRjPKE3sZYSDshATog2kgfQEH1nEvrl2AYqX2TCACaxya%2BcGMMU1IKxRdFyr00jX9/3CPBKVskK0CwBxgEBX1VQ3NMs0aPi3WQb5PFMKIfAAMSGb9gqxiR0H22Qibm2wt2mM9EoPB20vOzL8dxggKYK/1ey5pM3w/HabElmrOH6UhZC4ABWThSAELgrCT1AuCHLpOj4JhWHYLY2m8Wgk4IVPo5jtIQG8bxNRr%2BuG8b0ZY64FMk5Tzg09IDPOCThgQDFsvO%2Bj0g4FgGBEBQcwvJU8hKE8gSVJAYAQzaUhglkRl%2B4gNRy5WkJlxKLgS7W8xElogB5ZGj%2BHjbPiQmc98M1J4mU/vb8NVIHWPpOurj2/YZmB/jHN0ah%2B6QBjsiJy78HB0nzA4ZYm0/DIFoLQRwF9vCOAAOosmwWTYgvx6I6AUHmbBFR0AkLwPA5wrh4ieB8P4QI0J3ToD7iwNgHBaAgITu3PePc6QAA5RgOFGCmPgf58whk1HJCAuBCAkELsXKUzRp6L01kXLhpdy6elIFXGuddG6GJrs3f%2BbdSBAJDCmTUIYQyoKsAIgR8crApnjjYgRyc%2BFcD7gPUgQ804xzHpPTEZR%2BRzwgAvQSdBSA6HkcQOg3DOCJw8bfHu7Ri58DrIQCCgjhGiPEbLKRbQtHDx0SkG2S9Zgt04GYoBbR47SLaA4gAnKglMTT44plkmvDuXce7eMHtoyu1c2ialQaMEMDjvBtDGRM9x/9vC8JSV43x2jR4T0CRAJAETZ4UHCaoyJiFFBOLFhvLelBd63wmsyYgN8T68XPgQK%2B9Qn732nBwW%2Bz9jJvz3p/ZA39OAnz/nvQBwDY4cnAZUqBJkYGIIYcgbo3RUHoMwQ4HBmk8EMgIY4chlDqEuFhHQrwfgAhBBYWw/OnCElJJ6enLgOSRFiMOdEepVhNRWDPHIog6ilEtH2R9NJbR%2BjFP8UM/RRijFVJqSAARrKrCjFoFYbwIZRjeCaQImxTTumeN7owHxfiR4bKQME0JuztlxLXjErl8SqnUu1QKjJWS%2BD0ryUyvgLK2XCorqQMpWA4mVNMUnIBtAmmaiad4ARTTRhF3GLQWSVgQzJN6cs/uAySmiqsR0tVEzvAuLaeq5VVSFmJtpTq/VOj/5FOLd3ZZZaY7KWIAwEyIAUxAA%3D%3D).

gcc7.2 inlines `foo` through the weak alias call to `foo_void`!  clang doesn't, though.  I think that means that this is safe, and so is function-pointer casting, in gcc.  Alternatively it means that this is potentially dangerous, too. >.<

clang's undefined-behaviour sanitizer does runtime function typeinfo checking (in C++ mode only) for calls through function pointers.  `int ()` is different from `void ()`, so it will detect and report this UB on x86.  (See the asm on Godbolt).  It probably doesn't mean it's actually unsafe at the moment, though, because it doesn't yet detect / warn about it at compile time.

---

Use the above workarounds in the code that takes the address of the function, not in the code that receives a function pointer.

You want to let the compiler see a real function with the signature that it will eventually be called with, regardless of the function pointer type you pass it through.  Make an alias / wrapper with a signature that matches what the function pointer will eventually be cast to.  If that means you have to cast the function pointer to pass it in the first place, so be it.

(I think it's safe to create a pointer to the wrong type as long as it's not dereferenced.  It's UB to even create an unaligned pointer, even if you don't dereference, but that's different.)

If you have code that needs to deref the same function pointer as `int foo(args)` in one place and `void foo(args)` in another place, you're screwed as far as avoiding UB.

Comment: The problem with the wrapper is that it is not _generally_ applicable: sure in this trivial case you can wrap `foo` but the problem is that you may start with a function pointer in the first place, which you can't wrap (outside of some extensions like gcc's local functions), or it may be in generic/macro generated code where a wrapping isn't possible.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: I hesitate to encourage UB, even though I'm 99% sure it will continue to be safe here when it doesn't cause ABI issues.  Do you think it's reasonable to suggest that it's ok to do in practice when the workarounds aren't simple / efficient?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. There are a lot of soft considerations that come into a decision like that: will people die if it gets miscompiled at some point? Will saving a few nanoseconds make you really rich? Do you upgrade compilers often? Do you compile on different compilers, platforms? What is the cost of alternative, etc, etc? My comment wasn't really intended to promote UB but to kind of battle against the "you don't even need to do that, here's easy workaround X": because people demand minimal examples, a workaround often doesn't apply to the full case the example was generated from.

Comment: FWIW, I take a less benevolent view of the compiler behavior than you. I'm not sure if the compilers are really intentionally compiling this properly because they want to offer good QoI. In the case that the callee can't be statically determined or isn't visible (that's the interesting case, right?) the compiler is bound by the ABI: I don't see how how they could break this even if they wanted. In the case where the callee is known and visible (like the OPs) inlining the call seems to work: but is this an intentional design or does it just fall out of the behavior of the optimizer?

Comment: Put another way - are they actually doing any extra work in the compiler to make this work, or is it just currently a natural outcome? If it's the latter, I can entirely envision a future where more general use is made of UB to compile more efficiently: we have already plenty of cases of that, although limited to specific profitable areas like integer overflow, null pointer derefs, etc. There you can see that compiler makers already heavily favored optimization opportunities over what some might consider QoI (i.e., they broke the most common addition overflow check idiom and left it broken).

Comment: @BeeOnRope: that's a good point about assuming that paths that lead to UB are never taken.  That's a very plausible mechanism for breaking this code on purpose.  I don't think gcc currently makes any effort to *not* break this code, it just naturally doesn't.  e.g. you don't get a warning before gcc emits broken code that calls a function requiring a hidden pointer to the return value even when the definition is visible, so gcc just isn't thinking about this.  (And the unknown-pointer case just can't break because the compiler can't know it wasn't really a correct pointer in the wrong type.)

Comment: @BeeOnRope:  I think aggressively assuming that all paths that lead to any kind of UB would go too far.  I'd hope that a feature like that would let you control which kinds of UB it acted on.  I think this kind of pointer-casting would be one of the optional ones, if it was included at all.  My phrasing probably was too optimistic, I think based on not seeing a plausible mechanism for the compiler to do anything else.  But still, I suspect that this kind of thing happens in real code, maybe enough that gcc wouldn't want to break it.  At least not without an option or warning first.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: updated this answer to be less optimistic about UB being safe.  The workarounds all work in the code that takes the address of a function.

Answer (score 0):

**C11 §6.3.2.3 paragraph 8:**

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call
>   a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the
>   behavior is **undefined**.